# Causes for bug where starship is sent straight to orbit from ground?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I've noticed that every few take-offs, my starship will rapidly ascend into orbit for no reason. This didn't bother me until I read a comment that implied that going into orbit would reset your extreme weather survival timer. Because this milestone is already frustratingly time-consuming enough, I would like to not be thrown into space unwillingly and void the time I have spent waiting around for time to pass.

This bug is recorded in a bug report log here: http://steamcommunity.com/app/275850/discussions/2/360672137535982278/)

> Originally posted by Orbital Launch Glitch:
>   On occasion, using the launch boosters to enter flight from ground will cause the ship to rapidly gain altitude (resulting in instantaneous orbit).

It is also noted in the report that there is no known fix for this, but I'm thinking there has to be some kind of circumstances that cause this.

From what I've seen, it looks like every time this has happened, it's been during a storm of some type on whatever planet I am on. Can anyone confirm/refute this? Any other observations are welcome, too.

Comment: This has happened to me on temperate worlds where there are no storms...

Comment: Same here. Apologies if I was unclear. I meant that it happens much more frequently on planets during storms, from my own experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the specific cause still remains unclear, the issue has been fixed, according to [patch notes](http://www.playstationlifestyle.net/2016/08/28/no-mans-sky-update-1-07-live-ps4/#/slide/1) from the latest patch (1.07).

> Fixed an issue that would cause your ship to be thrown in the sky at high speed when taking off (in rare cases could in turn lead to getting stuck).

Answer (score 5):

I believe that I have been able to reproduce this behavior fairly consistently by **landing close to and facing a large mineral deposit** and then harvesting it. You don't need to be on it nor clipping through it (or any other terrain), and I am not sure if harvesting is required.

It may be that the launch thrusters move you forward into the terrain deformation (harvested deposit) and then the auto-altitude routine that prevents you from crashing into terrain uses your current (excessive) vertical acceleration to make the correction.

The work-around is to make sure you park so the deposit is not in your front-facing field of view.

Comment: Yep I noticed too, I think this is because of the you can't fly down to the ground thing they implemented. I'm thinking that if you install the mod that makes you able to fly all the way to the ground and below will fix this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have it on PS4 so installing mods isn't an option (at the moment)

Comment: I wonder if this is also why my game kept crashing when trying to take off right by a deposit.

Comment: I ran into this a couple times when the deposit was behind me. I wouldn't park anywhere near one, just to be safe.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue previously on every other take-off or so and it was extremely annoying. I'm not sure since when, 1.04 or 1.05, but it is fixed for me since then on PS4. It then only appeared one single time and that was when I landed too close to a pillar. I think the ship was even partially parked in that pillar. Then at take-off it got stuck and after a second jumped up into space.

So my guess on this is, this happens as some kind of safeguard to not get your spaceship stuck without being able to land or take off - and previously (at least for me) some parameters have been off and triggered that behavior too soon.

In case you got the latest update installed and still have this, then the only other guess I have is that it depends on the spaceship. I was grinding spaceship upgrades so was switching spaceships a lot. Maybe it only is an issue with the Rasamama you get in the beginning.

Comment: Just as a note, it still happens for me on PS4 after 1.05. Current ship is Uenohash.

Comment: That's interesting that it happens when your ship clips through terrain... I think mine does that more often than not, honestly, so I'm pretty sure mine doesn't get sent to orbit every time it does it. But like @pushasha said, I've experienced this bug in other ships besides the preorder bonus ship.